# Synergy CM equivalent of SVN Externals?

Tags: version-control, svn-externals, cm-synergy

Trying to determine if there is any behavior analogous to SVN:Externals in IBM Rational Synergy CM.

Ultimate objective is to find a more integrated way for Synergy projects existing in one database to contain files originating from another database without manually copying them to the second database and manually propagating changes. SVN of course supports this through the concept of Externals which allow you point to directories or files even on a different repository.

Search has revealed nothing so far, and unfortunately use of Synergy is mandated in this situation so switching revision control tools is not an option. If manual copying is the answer, so be it, just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to share projects and files between databases is the DCM concept (see [manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdp/v1r0m0/topic/com.ibm.help.download.synergy.doc/pdf71/dcm.pdf)) . However, it's quite complicated to use and require some scripting in order to function properly. If you have simple needs you can always do it "outside" Synergy with a simple file/directory repository.

Comment: Thank you, I don't believe we have DCM configured within my organization's deployment of Synergy but it certainly is helpful to know IBM's intended solution to this.